# PHP Array within the for loop

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

Is there a way to create an array within the for loop. There are several similar answers here, but none of them or the logic from these answers is applicable in the code below.

```
for($j=1;$j<6;$j++) {
    $odg[$j] = "";
}
//the rest of the code which gives values to the array elements (outside the loop)
```

This is how array should look like before insert it into the sql query.

```
$odg_ids = array($odg[1],$odg[2],$odg[3],$odg[4],$odg[5]);
$odg_list = implode("','", $odg_ids);
```

This is the for loop that should generate an array.

```
for($i=1;$i<6;$i++) {
    $odg_ids[] = $odg[$i];
    $odg_list[] = implode("','", $odg_ids[$i]);
}
```

Something's missing?

Comment: take `$odg_list[] = implode("','", $odg_ids);` out of the loop?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Show us 1) what you expect to get, 2) your code, 3) what you actually get, and 4) any error messages you encounter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to do the `implode` *after* the loop.  Otherwise you keep appending to `odg_list` each time.

```
for ($i=1;$i<6;$i++) {
    $odg_ids[] = $odg[$i];
}
$odg_list = implode("','", $odg_ids[$i]);
```

I'm not sure where you get `6` from, but you could also use `array_slice` to get the 1st through 6th elements (you are omitting the 0th element).

Comment: @mpavlovic89 by the way, if `odg_ids` is user input you probably shouldn't be using this generated string in a query.

Comment: Just to add that in implode function there should be [$i] - it works without it.